# Transverse Flux Machine

Tags: electromagnetism, induction-motor, magnetics, magnetic-flux

For research, I want to build a levitation system that can levitate an aluminum sheet. With traditional 3 phase Induction engines you off course get levitation, but it isn't as stable as I want to. I've seen some Transverse Flux machines that are combined with a Linear Induction Engine. I know that Transverse Flux machines are based on an inward traveling magnetic field. But I wasn't able to understand how Professor Laithwaite created this stable levitation in the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5mA4l6xmGs (t=11:20).

There are two rows of (I suggest) coils that are both creating a magnetic field to the inside?
Or is there a magnetic field traveling from row A to row B?
Please help me out! Thank you

Comment: I think there may be two rows but the sheet stabilizes in the middle due to gravity in that it's easier to sit a little bit lower (in the middle) where the field is weaker. To try and rise it needs to fight a little against gravity and so it finds equilibrium in the middle where the magnetic field is slightly less. I'm not making this an answer; I'm just commenting.

Comment: I think that @Andy aka may be correct. However I think it is also possible to shape the magnetic field with a single row of coils used with a core and aluminum piece that is shaped in a certain way. If I have time, I will try to find what Laithwaite has published about it.

Answer (score 0):

Laithwaite first built a system using two rows of "C" cores and then found that a single row would do the job as shown in the following photo.

[image]

E.R. Laithwaite "Linear Propulsion by 'Electromagnetic River'", in Production Engineer Vol 53, no. 7.8, pp 219-223, Jul/Aug 1974